# gcc mips signed arithmetic on bytes

Tags: c, gcc, mips

I have fed this simple code to gcc

```
   volatile  signed char x, y, z;

void test()
{
    x = 0x31;
    y = x + 3;
}
```

Volatile has been added just to avoid gcc optimization (set to -O0 anyway).
Resulting mips code was:

```
x:
y:
z:
test():
  addiu $sp,$sp,-8
  sw $fp,4($sp)
  move $fp,$sp
  lui $2,%hi(x)
  li $3,49 # 0x31
  sb $3,%lo(x)($2)
  lui $2,%hi(x)
  lbu $2,%lo(x)($2)
  seb $2,$2
  andi $2,$2,0x00ff
  addiu $2,$2,3
  andi $2,$2,0x00ff
  seb $3,$2
  lui $2,%hi(y)
  sb $3,%lo(y)($2)
  nop
  move $sp,$fp
  lw $fp,4($sp)
  addiu $sp,$sp,8
  j $31
  nop
```

For (y= x+3) gcc loads the byte as unsigned and then sign extend it and then or it with 0xff? 
why not simply load it using lb (which is supposed to sign extend it)?
GCC does the same for signed half words (using 0xffff of course).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly adept at reading MIPS assembly, but do note that you have compiled with `-O0`, which is supposed to generate unoptimized code.  That more or less means code that implements the exact semantics of the C abstract machine.  In particular,

- `0x31` is a constant of type `int`
- the assignment `x = 0x31` includes an implicit conversion (in this case) of the right-hand `int` operand to the type of the left-hand operand (`signed char`)
- `3` is also a constant of type `int`
- evaluating `x + 3` involves performing the integer promotions on the arguments, and in particular, converting the `signed char` value of `x` to (signed) `int`, then performing the addition
- assigning the result to `y` involves another implicit conversion from `int` to `signed char`

In principle, all of those conversions and promotions that are implicit in the C code need to be performed explicitly by the unoptimized assembly program, and that appears roughly to be what you are seeing.

Overall, it's not very useful to ask why the assembly output of a non-optimizing compilation is not as efficient as you think it could be.  If you want more efficient code, *enable optimization*.

Answer (score 0):

gcc -march=native -O3 gives the following code on an Intel machine:

```
test:
    .seh_endprologue
    movb    $49, x(%rip)
    movzbl  x(%rip), %eax
    addl    $3, %eax
    movb    %al, y(%rip)
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .comm   z, 1, 0
    .comm   y, 1, 0
    .comm   x, 1, 0
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.4.0"
```

There's nothing wrong with your code. gcc/MIPS just isn't very good at code generation, which is not too surprising since it receives a lot less care and attention than gcc/Intel. In my experience clang usually generates better MIPS code than gcc does.